# What is the appropriate way to set a VB StringBuilder to an empty string?

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I'm using VB's StringBuilder, and I was curious what is considered "best practice" for emptying the builder/setting it to a new string. Would it be something like this:

```
Dim str As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
str.Append("Some string to remove")
str = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
str.Append("Ahh, fresh new text!")
```

or is there a "Better" way?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually just use:

```
str.Length = 0
```

Comment: That makes sense, and looks a lot cleaner to boot!

Comment: Is there any idiomatic way to reset a string builder to some particular content (equivalent to `Dim MyString As New StringBuilder("whatever")` but without declaring and creating a new instance)?  Setting length to zero and then appending is the best way I know, but it seems rather hokey.

Comment: @supercat In .NET 4 a `Clear` followed by `Append` is almost identical to what the `.ctor` does. In .NET 3.5/2.0 this is also true, unless you happen to be on a different thread to when the `StringBuilder` was last changed. Then it is much better to create a new `StringBuilder` to avoid the complete duplication of the current content _before_ the `Length` is zeroed out!

Answer (score 6):

In .Net 4, they have added a Clear method for that purpose.

Comment: .NET 4+ users should use `.Clear`, but .NET 3.5/2.0 users don't worry, it's implementation is `.Length = 0`.